# Copy link option in VueJS component not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

In my laravel/vue application, I'm having an option to copy a link when a user clicks on an icon.

So far I have following in my component

```
 <a href="sample.site" class="text-dark" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" ref="mylink">
    <img class="social_icon"  @click="copyURL($refs.mylink)"
      src="/images/game/copy.png"
    /></a>
    <p>copied: {{ link }}</p>
```

and I have the following in my

```
<script>
export default {
  
};
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        link: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      copyURL(link) {
        this.link = link.href
      }
    }

})
</script>
```

But this is not working or not showing any errors

Comment: Where you call **copyURL** ? and show output from **console.log(Url.innerHTML)**

Answer (score 0):

You have not called the method `copyURL`

```
<a :href="sample.site" @click="copyURL" ref="mylink">
  <img class="social_icon" src="/images/game/copy.png" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the link to be copied in the user's clipboard so that he can then paste it somewhere else, you have to do this:

```js
const inputElement = document.querySelector(elementSelector);
inputElement.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
```

Now the user has the value copied in the clipboard.

Note that the `document.execCommand('copy')` command can only be applied to input-type elements.